# positional indexers are out-of-bounds when filtering dataframe on existing value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working on beginners problem for multiclass classification on Kaggle:

Data available here:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00314054107124324293

My anaconda has just been updated to the newest version (pyton3, windows10 setup).

```
## usual imports
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
%matplotlib inline

train = pd.read_csv('./train.csv', sep=',', low_memory=False, index_col='Id')
test = pd.read_csv('./test.csv', sep=',', low_memory=False, index_col='Id')
```

Then I wanted to check correlations between features with this simple loop:

```
## check numeric features: columns 10:-1

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (10,8)
covers = list(train.Cover_Type.unique())
covers.sort()
for cover_type in covers:
    print(f'Cover Type: {cover_type}\n')
    mask = train[train['Cover_Type']==cover_type].index
    sns.heatmap(train.iloc[mask,:10].corr(),annot=True)
    plt.show();
```

it works okay until I hit **Cover_Type 3**, then it throws an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-c559c9b2bf10> in <module>
  9 
 10     plt.figure(figsize=(10,8))
---> 11     sns.heatmap(train.iloc[mask,:10].corr(),annot=True)
 12     plt.show();

    ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1492             except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1493                 pass
-> 1494             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1495         else:
   1496             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   2141     def _getitem_tuple(self, tup):
   2142 
-> 2143         self._has_valid_tuple(tup)
   2144         try:
   2145             return self._getitem_lowerdim(tup)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _has_valid_tuple(self, key)
221                 raise IndexingError('Too many indexers')
222             try:
--> 223                 self._validate_key(k, i)
224             except ValueError:
225                 raise ValueError("Location based indexing can only have "

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py in _validate_key(self, key, axis)
   2079 
   2080             if len(arr) and (arr.max() >= len_axis or arr.min() < -len_axis):
-> 2081                 raise IndexError("positional indexers are out-of-bounds")
   2082         else:
   2083             raise ValueError("Can only index by location with "

IndexError: positional indexers are out-of-bounds

<Figure size 720x576 with 0 Axes>
```

Why this is the case?

Comment: This can happen when you use `iloc` when you actually wanted to use `loc`. The first is based on integer location and the second is based on label. Did you check if that's the case here?

Comment: Why Cover Types 1,2,4,5,6,7 sets correct index with .iloc[]?

Comment: OK, I ran the code with your data and got everything as expected. So it seems to be a version issue. I ran the code on colab.research.google.com, which has python 3.6.8, pandas 0.24.2, numpy 1.16.5 and seaborn 0.9.0.